# nodeJS - how to get 'ESTIMATED_DELIVERY' from fedex?

Tags: node.js, schema, fedex

I'm using [node-shipping-fedex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-shipping-fedex) for create/tracking shipment.
I want 'ESTIMATED_DELIVERY' date, but not able to get it in response.

[Tracking Service Options](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/webhelp/ws/2018/US/index.htm#t=wsdvg%2FTracking_Shipments.htm%23Tracking_Service_Optionsbc-3&rhtocid=_26_0_2) in Fedex Doc.

```
let fedex = new fedexAPI({
    environment: 'sandbox',
    debug: true,
    key: configSite.fedexKey,
    password: configSite.fedexpassword,
    account_number: configSite.fedexAccountNo,
    meter_number: configSite.fedexMeterNo,
    imperial: true, // set to false for metric
});

fedex.track({
    SelectionDetails: {
        PackageIdentifier: {
            Type: 'TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG',
            Value: trackId,
        },
    },
    ProcessingOptions: 'INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS',
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('TRACKING ERR: ', err);
        return reject(err);
    }
    console.log('RESP: ', res);
});
```

Any help will appreciated. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.